# Getting Particular Values From XML Document

Tags: c#, xml, devexpress

I'm trying to get some values from an XML Document.
Here is the Xml Document that being generated from [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<XtraSerializer version="15.2.5.0">
<Items>
<Item1 SelectedStencils="" CanvasSizeMode="AutoSize" PageSize="40000,40000" 
Theme="Office" ItemKind="DiagramRoot" Size="40000,40000">
<Children>
<Item1 ItemKind="DiagramShape" Size="100,75" Shape="BasicShapes.Rectangle" 
Position="19500,19440"/>
<Item2 ItemKind="DiagramShape" Size="100,90" Shape="BasicShapes.Triangle" 
Position="19540,19660"/>
<Item3 ItemKind="DiagramConnector" EndPoint="19590,19660" 
BeginPoint="19550,19515" EndItem="1" BeginItem="0" Points="19550,19650 
19590,19650" EndArrow="Filled90"/>
<Item4 ItemKind="DiagramShape" Size="100,75" Shape="BasicShapes.Rectangle" 
Position="19940,19440"/>
<Item5 ItemKind="DiagramConnector" EndPoint="19940,19477.5" 
BeginPoint="19600,19477.5" EndItem="3" BeginItem="0" Points="" 
EndArrow="Filled90"/>
<Item6 ItemKind="DiagramConnector" EndPoint="19940,19477.5" 
BeginPoint="19590,19660" EndItem="3" BeginItem="1" Points="19590,19525 
19930,19525 19930,19478" EndArrow="Filled90"/>
</Children>
</Item1>
</Items>
</XtraSerializer>
```

I'm trying to get the values "BeginItem" & "EndItem" from the "DiagramConnector" part.
I tried to get these values with the DevExpress API [BeginItem](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Diagram.DiagramConnector.BeginItem.property) -- [EndItem](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Diagram.DiagramConnector.EndItem.property)
but each time I try, the values are always Null even though when the data is saved, its not null in the XML Document.
So I figured getting the values directly from the XML document would be the best/only way.

Here is how I'm trying to get the values from the xml document.
keep in mind that there could be a million DiagramConnection Objects.

```
class Program
{
    static readonly string FolderLocation = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\Diagram Samples";
    static readonly string FileName = "d.xml";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string FullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(FolderLocation, FileName);

        using (XmlDocumentCreator xmlDocument = new XmlDocumentCreator(FullPath))
        {
            string data = xmlDocument.ReadDocument.ToString();
            if (data.Contains("BeginItem") && data.Contains("EndItem"))
            {
                string xpath = "Items/Item1SelectedStencils/Children";
                var nodes = xmlDocument.XMLDocument.SelectNodes(xpath);

                foreach (XmlNode childrenNode in nodes)
                {
                    Console.Write(childrenNode.SelectSingleNode("//BeginItem").Value);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

And Here is my XML Document class I created,
 I know its not correct for this project as SelectNodes requires an XmlDocument, its just for testing.

```
class XmlDocumentCreator : IDisposable
{
    public XmlDocument XMLDocument { get; set; }

    // <summary>
    /// XmlDocument Creator
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xmlDocumentPath">xmlPath</param>
    public XmlDocumentCreator(string xmlDocumentPath)
    {
        XMLDocument = new XmlDocument();
        XMLDocument.Load(xmlDocumentPath);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns An Xml Document
    /// Which Can Then Be Read.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public XElement ReadDocument
    {
        get
        {
            if (XMLDocument != null)
            {
                return XElement.Parse(XMLDocument.InnerXml);
            }
            throw new Exception("XML Document Object Was Not Created");
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Will Dispose The XML Document
    /// And Also Call The Garbage Collector.
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (XMLDocument != null)
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            GC.Collect();
            Console.WriteLine("XML Document Object Disposed");
        }
    }
}
```

In a perfect world, once I can get the values that are needed during the loop for each value on I could put them to an [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) and do with them whatever.

Comment: `//Items/Item1[@SelectedStencils]/Children` may get you started.

Comment: it certainly has gotten me one step closer thats for sure, cheers mate